# How strange the textinput method behavior in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

#### The version of Jquery and Jquery Mobile

```
jquery-1.9.1.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js
```

#### I have some tests about the textinput plugin of `input` element

This is my code

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="content">
        <form>
            <label for="text-1">Text input:</label>
            <input type="text" name="text-1" id="text-1" value="">

            <input type="button" name="text-3" class="btnFinish" value="Finish">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on('pageinit', function () {
        $('#text-1').textinput({ theme: 'a' });
        $('.btnFinish').buttonMarkup({corners: false });
    });
</script>
```

The text input element's theme is **not changed**. But when I comment the pageinit event, the text input element's theme will **be changed**.

```
<script>
        //$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
            $('#text-1').textinput({ theme: 'a' });
            $('.btnFinish').buttonMarkup({corners: false });
        //});
</script>
```

And I've try other events just like `pagecreate`, `pageload`, `pageshow`, the text input are all not be changed.

And I also tried the ready event in jquery, it's not effective too.

But `$('.btnFinish').buttonMarkup({corners: false });` is always effective.

And the conclusion is that "The textinput method is effective not in any event?", I think it is very strange. Someone can explain it? Thx very much.

Comment: Have you simply tried ``$(document).ready(function () { ... });``?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. It's not effective. And the answer below solved my question absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something always do it in a correct way.

First when using page events always bind it to a certain page or all of them, like this:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#index', function(){ 
    $('#text-1').textinput({ theme: 'a' });
    $('.btnFinish').buttonMarkup({corners: false });
});
```

or this:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '.ui-page', function(){ 

});
```

Also because some jQuery Mobile widgets are little bit messy when you are changing a theme always try to do it in a **[pagecreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)** or a **[pagebeforcreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforecreate/)** event. Mainly because at this point jQuery Mobile is still waiting to enhance HTML markup.

#### Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/104/

#### Javascript used:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#index', function(){ 
    $('#text-1').textinput({ theme: 'a' });
    $('.btnFinish').buttonMarkup({corners: false });
});
```

Last advice, never use document ready with jQuery Mobile (what ever people tell you). There are several reasons for that, read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**.

If you have more questions feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask a question again. Is there a method to change theme or other options programmingly such as in button's click event?

    $('.btnFinish').click(function () {
         $('#text-1').textinput({ theme: 'a' });
    });